# MySql select average with compare rows where having average within condition

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
id   sup_id    cp_id    max      limit     bal 
---- --------- ------- -------- ---------- ---
1     79        4      10         2        2     
2     79        44     12         2        7     
3     79        23     10         2        1
4     79        2      10         3        3
5     80        4      10         2        7
6     80        2      10         3        4
7     80        44     12         2        1
```

I have a table above, and I would like to write a query to select `id`, `sub_id`,`cp_id`, `max`, `bal` based on `sub_id` for those `bal` is less equal than `limit` and the average number of `(bal <= limit)` over total of rows is `>=` 0.6. The result should show as below

```
id   sup_id    cp_id    max       bal 
---- --------- ------- --------  ---
1     79        4      10          2     
3     79        23     10          1
4     79        2      10          3
```

Can someone show me how it should write in mysql query? thanks

Comment: Can you explain *the average number of instance*?

Comment: sorry to make you confuse. I had just amended my question. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM tablename t
WHERE t.bal <= `limit`
AND (SELECT AVG(bal <= `limit`) FROM tablename WHERE sup_id = t.sup_id) >= 0.6
```

Or join the table to this query:

```
SELECT sup_id
FROM tablename
GROUP BY sup_id
HAVING AVG(bal <= `limit`) >= 0.6
```

which returns only the `sup_id`s that satisfy your 2nd condition:

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM tablename t 
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT sup_id
  FROM tablename
  GROUP BY sup_id
  HAVING AVG(bal <= `limit`) >= 0.6
) g ON g.sup_id = t.sup_id
WHERE t.bal <= `limit`
```

For MySql 8.0+ you could use `AVG()` window function in a subquery:

```
SELECT t.id, t.sup_id, t.cp_id, t.max, t.`limit`, t.bal
FROM (
  SELECT *, AVG(bal <= `limit`) OVER (PARTITION BY sup_id) avg_instance
  FROM tablename
) t
WHERE t.bal <= t.`limit` and avg_instance >= 0.6
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a4d7b9176abbc9ed9e9b5295441693dc).
Results:

```
> id | sup_id | cp_id | max | limit | bal
> -: | -----: | ----: | --: | ----: | --:
>  1 |     79 |     4 |  10 |     2 |   2
>  3 |     79 |    23 |  10 |     2 |   1
>  4 |     79 |     2 |  10 |     3 |   3
```

Comment: yes, your solutions might be correct, because if I had changed the avg_instance >= 0.9 it should not give me any return right?

Comment: Check this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=47e581c82b0b50c0e094ec8cbc15c5f2